# How to use the string from editText as display textview in another activity?

Tags: android, eclipse

I want to use the string which is typed in `edittext` as `textview` in a new activity.

```
sub6 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText16);
        txt6 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView25);
        subject = (String) sub6.getText().toString();
        txt6.setText(getResources().getString(R.id.editText16));
```

I have used this code. But is of no use. Can you please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send the string using Bundle

```
Intent i=new Intent(A.this, B.class);                
            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putString("name", sub6.getText().toString());           
            i.putExtras(b);
            startActivity(i);
```

and in the receiving activity:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 
String text = extras.getString("name");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I do it:

```
EditText sub6 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext16);
TextView txt6 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview25);
String subject = sub6.getText().toString();
txt6.setText(subject);
```

You do a lot of unnecessary casts. Like your third line casts a String to a String. Which is useless. Also, declare the object types (like String, EditText, etc.) before declaring them.

Answer (score 0):

In MainActivity,send the string using intent

```
sub6 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText16);
txt6 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView25);
subject = sub6.getText().toString();
Intent in=new Intent(FirstActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
in.putExtra("key",subject);
startActivity(in);
```

In the second Activity recieve intent using getIntent() andthe string using key  getStringExtra()

```
Intent in=getIntent();
String s=in.getStringExtra("key");
txt6.setText(s);
```